# ¿Como obtener la suma de todos los numero obtenidos dentro de un forEach?

Tags: javascript, bucles, angular7, foreach

necesito obtener el total de unidades tras recorrer el siguiente array de objetos:

```
{
  "added": [
    {
      "functional_id": "recharges",
      "quantity": 9
    },
    {
      "functional_id": "modeles",
      "quantity": 4
    },
    {
      "functional_id": "coffrets",
      "quantity": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

para ello recorro el array de objetos con el siguiente forEach

```
    this.cart.added.forEach(item => {
      const adder = item.quantity;
      const sum = 0 + adder;
      console.log(sum);
    });
```

pero como veis no se como obtener la suma total de los 'quantity'

Alguien que me de una idea de lo que debo hacer!
Gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás creando la variable como constante dentro del `forEach` por lo que para cada Item, se reinicia.

Debes declararla fuera como variable y modificarla dentro.

Esto se llama [**Ámbito de una variable**](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/javascript/capitulo-4/ambito-de-las-variables):

> El ámbito de una variable (llamado "scope" en inglés) es la zona del
>   programa en la que se define la variable. JavaScript define dos
>   ámbitos para las variables: global y local.

En tu caso, la variable (realmente era una constante) era local, por lo que únicamente tenía el valor dentro de la función. Es decir, "en cada vuelta" del forEach. Necesitas por tanto declararla como "global" para que cada vuelta actualice esa variable global que te vale como sumatorio.

```
var sum=0;

this.cart.added.forEach(item => {
      const adder = item.quantity;
      sum = sum + adder;
      console.log(sum);
    });
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias, sabia que algo estaba haciendo mal, pero no me daba cuenta!!

Answer (score 3):

Otra forma de obtener este resultado es con [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)

```js
var cart = {
  "added": [
    {
      "functional_id": "recharges",
      "quantity": 9
    },
    {
      "functional_id": "modeles",
      "quantity": 4
    },
    {
      "functional_id": "coffrets",
      "quantity": 3
    }
  ]
}

 var r = this.cart.added.reduce((a, b) =>  a+= b.quantity ,0)
 
 console.log('Resultado', r)
```

Comment: Interesante, si bien no responde a su problema!!! ;)  +1 tb

Comment: Si, de echo, es la idea. Tu respuesta es la que resuelve el problema.

Comment: @Legna probandolo tambien funciona! muchas gracias, llevo poco tiempo programando y agradezco ver distintas formas de afrontar un  problema!